# Looking for good resources for interface patterns not related to web or mobile

Tags: design-patterns

I know there are lot of resources for examples of excellent interface design for web and mobile but I'm looking for some design patterns outside of those spheres. Preferably **appliance type interfaces** are what I'm looking for but anything will do.

Answer (score 1):

the design of everyday things by donald normal lists alot of good and poor ones.

ie doors where the push and pull is the same handle vs a flat surface to push and a bar to pull.

poor faucets vs good ones.

different cars and household appliances.  there may be some industrial design books with some too

[normans book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465067107)

Comment: Thanks. Thats a great book, one of the first I read about interfaces. I am also looking for maybe a website where I can browse lots of examples.